# Random distorted images in Windows

Tags: windows, display, windows-11

I have an HP Omen laptop running Windows 11. It has a 1080p display, and both integrated Intel graphics as well as an NVidia Geforce GTX 965M graphics card. I believe the laptop is a 2016 model but I'm not sure.

I'm having an issue with display distortion in random parts of Windows. Sometimes, when I open an application, open the Taskbar Widgets overlay, etc. parts of what is showing on my screen becomes distorted, while other parts remain normal - the effect created looks almost like a human fingerprint. However, I noticed that when I take screenshots, the distortion is somehow captured by the screenshot, like in this screenshot of WhatsApp for Windows (notice the effect on the chat profile pictures):

[Image showing display distortion in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MK0EM.png)

Usually, the distortion effect takes a couple of seconds to fully appear - i.e. when I open Windows Widgets, the distortion effect takes about 2 seconds to load/appear fully (it "fades in").

The occurrence of this distortion appears to be quite random - i.e. sometimes it appears, sometimes it doesn't, sometimes it appears in new places, disappears again, etc.

There is nothing wrong with my display, as I use the same hardware to run Ubuntu and Windows from portable drives, I have only ever experienced this issue when running my local Windows installation.

How can I stop this from happening, so everything appears normal?

Comment: What exactly is the version of the HP Omen laptop and what's your display card?

Comment: @harrymc I have updated the question to include the graphics card details. I'm not sure how to find the laptop version, however, I have included what I believe the age of the laptop to be.

Comment: Do you use the latest [NVIDIA Driver Downloads](https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx)?

Comment: @harrymc I have not tried the drivers. I've never had this issue before (even without installing NVidia's drivers), however, I will install them when I next boot into Windows and update my question accordingly. Thank you

Comment: *even without installing NVidia's drivers* That's the problem, this false sense of security... Only with Nvidia proprietary drivers installed and running you can use the graphics to its full potential and only then confirm the hardware is fine. I bet you DON'T have other than *nouveau* running in Ubuntu so it doesn't matter for hardware troubleshooting because it hardly ·"stresses" the GPU...